# How to pass JSON String to Jersey Rest Web-Service with Post Request

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-ws

I want to create a REST Jersey Web-Service accepting JSON string as input parameter.

Also I will use post requestand from  webmethod I will return one JSON string.

How can I consume this in a HTML page using Ajax post request. 
I want to know what all changes I need to make it on web method to accept JSON String.

```
 public class Hello {

      @POST
     public String sayPlainTextHello() {
      return "Hello Jersey";
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Need to break down your requests.  First, you want to accept a JSON string.  So on your method you need

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Next, you need to decide what you want your method to obtain.  You can obtain a JSON string, as you suggest, in which case your method would look like this:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sayPlainTextHello(final String input) {
```

Or alternatively if your JSON string maps to a Java object you could take the object directly:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sayPlainTextHello(final MyObject input) {
```

You state that you want to return a JSON string.  So you need:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

And then you need to actually return a JSON string:

```
return "{\"result\": \"Hello world\"}";
```

So your full method looks something like this:

```
@PATH("/hello")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sayPlainTextHello(final String input) {
  return "{\"result\": \"Hello world\"}";
}
```

Regarding using AJAX to send and receive, it would look something like this:

```
var myData="{\"name\": \"John\"}";
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/hello",
    type: "post",
    data: myData
});

request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log("Response from server: " + response);
});
```

Comment: @jgm..can u pls tell how to pass value and consume it in html page using ajax request..

Comment: Updated response to cover AJAX

Comment: Did it work?  If so please mark the response as answered, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. "path" is the relative URL path to be used in AJAX call.

```
public class Hello {

@POST
@Path("/path")
@Produces({ "text/html" })
 public String sayPlainTextHello() {
  return "Hello Jersey";
  }
```

}